# SQL Query to Find relevant items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

We have a system that uses Electronic Forms but the standard searching functionality of the forms is very sub par, so I have been tasked with trying to create a better approach for the users.

Ok so a little background of the current database format :

```
Table1
------
FormID
FormName
Creator
CreateDate

Table2
------
FormID
FormControlName
ControlData
```

The relationship is a 1 to Many with there being many controls on one form.

My task is to create a search that will find the relevant forms by searching the form name (changes based on data) and each of the form Controls that belong to that form.

I have managed to do this using C# coding but because there is a high number of records in the Database, and the fact that in my Current solution I am retrieving everything and iterating over it to find the relevant items, it is quite a slow solution.

**My Code :**

```
private DataTable GetForms() {
    string FormName = ddForm.SelectedValue;
    string SearchText = tbSearch.Text;

    List<string> FormIDs = GetMatchingForms(FormName, SearchText);

    DataTable dtForms = new DataTable("Forms Table");

    dtForms.Columns.Add("Form Name");
    dtForms.Columns.Add("Initiator");
    dtForms.Columns.Add("Start Date").DataType = typeof(DateTime);
    dtForms.Columns.Add("FormLink");

    foreach (string FormID in FormIDs) {
        DataRow nRow = dtForms.NewRow();

        nRow[0] = GetData.GetString("SELECT [FormName] FROM [Table1] Where [FormID] = '" + FormID + "'", conString);

        string UserID = GetData.GetString("SELECT [Creator] FROM [Table1] Where [FormID] = '" + FormID + "'", conString);
        string UserName = GetData.GetString("Select [UserName] From [User] Where [UserID] = '" + UserID + "'", conString);
        nRow[1] = UserName;

        nRow[2] = GetData.GetString("SELECT [CreateDate] FROM [Table1] Where [FormID] = '" + FormID + "'", conString);
        nRow[3] = "~/Form.aspx?formid=" + FormID;

        dtForms.Rows.Add(nRow);
    }

    return dtForms;
}
private List<string> GetMatchingForms(string FormName, string SearchText) {
    //FormName can be = % to search all forms
    DataTable dtForms = GetData.GetDT("SELECT * FROM [Table1] Where [FormName] LIKE '%" + FormName + "%'", conString);

    List<string> FormList = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dtForms.Rows) {
        string FormName = row["FormName"].ToString();
        string FormID = row["FormID"].ToString();

        bool Relevant = false;

        if (FormName.Contains(SearchText)) {
            Relevant = true;
        } else {
            DataTable dtFormControls = GetData.GetDT("SELECT * FROM [Table2] Where [FormID] = '" + FormID + "'", conString);

            foreach (DataRow cRow in dtFormControls.Rows) {
                string ControlData = cRow["ControlData"].ToString();

                if (ControlData.Contains(SearchText)) {
                    Relevant = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Relevant) {
            FormList.Add(FormID);
        }
    }

    return FormList;
}
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to replicate the above code's functionality into a SQL Query (or a small number of queries) to hopefully try and speed up the current solution. My current knowledge of SQL Queries is not the best and I can't even begin to think of where to start with this issue.

To clarify, we currently have 300,000 forms and a total of 10.4 million data records, the database has been re indexed recently and that does seem to effect performance positively. We are planning on doing maintenance on this relatively soon but we will still be keeping the bulk of the data that is currently stored.

Edit : The Database in question is part of 3rd party software and we are limited to Read-Only access, database modifications are no possible for us.

As you can see from the number of records that the timing issue is quite a big one, as it literally takes minutes to execute the current code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance problems are because you are running four queries (3 againsts Table1 and 1 against User) for each string in your list, which is a big overhead.  I'd recommend one of the following (please bear in mind I don't have access to your database, so sorry for any coding errors)

1) Use LinqToSql

If you use LinqToSql then you can extract the data from the first part of your query with something similar to the following:

```
var myResults = (from t in context.Table1
                 join u in context.User on t.UserId equals u.UserId
                 where formIds.Contains (t.FormId)
                 select new { t.FormName, t.Creator, t.CreateDate }).ToList();
```

The Contains method allows you to effectively join your in memory data with data from the database, removing the need to loop for each item.

2) Use Database query

The equivalent SQL statement would be:

```
select t.FormName, t.Creator, t.CreateDate
from Table1 t
inner join [User] u on t.UserID = u.UserId
where t.FormId in (<list of formIDs here>)
```

You could either create a SQL command, building this string which is not recommended because of SQL Injection concerns or alternatively you could create a parameterised query or a stored procedure which is far better from a security perspective.

All of the above only applies to the first part of your code, but can easily be replicated for the 2nd part.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have a limited knowledge of LINQ, would using it provide any better performance than using standard ADO.NET query as you provided in your second suggestion?

Comment: In theory LINQ is slower, but there are various things you can do to mitigate such as not setting object tracking (when you are just reading data) and using compiled functions. If speed is the absolute #1 priority then I'd recommend a stored procedure.  I've only ever twice used something other than LINQ for reading from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've implemented something similar to your suggestion, the performance issue still persists but I don't think it can be negated. I will just have to add more Search Parameters for the user to enter to narrow the Search.

Answer (score 1):

A 1 to N relationship can be easily created in TSQL.  The sample program below adds primary keys for both the form id and control id with a foreign key relationship.

This will return the data you want in one record set versus multiple calls you are making before.

The next question is what type of data is the control data?  That is where you might be having the issues.

If it is defined as a varchar(max) or text, then you have to perform a full table scan.  You can not use a regular index < 900 bytes.

A index or balanced tree search is a N LOG(N) operation at worst versus a table search which is a N operation.  This is analysis of algorithms, order of magnitude, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, O(N LOG(N)) versus O(N).

With N = 11 M, you only have to look at 1.04 M rows max.  This is assuming a binary tree.  SQL server uses B+tree. http://sqlity.net/en/563/index-misconceptions-tsql-tuesday-026-second-chances/

If the control data field is text, you want to apply full text indexing.  Look at my blog articles http://craftydba.com/?p=1421 and/or presentation on how to set one up.  You will have to use the CONTAINS() or FREETEXT() functions for searching.

This index can be built right after a data load but provides you with superior speed versus a traditional LIKE clause.  This pushes the search load (computation) onto the SQL server instead of the client (web server).

I hope this helps you out,

If you have any more questions, just ask.

Sincerely

John

```
--
-- Sample table 1
--

create table tempdb.dbo.forms
(
    FormID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    FormName varchar(32),
    Creator varchar(32) DEFAULT (coalesce(suser_sname(),'?')),
    CreateDate smalldatetime DEFAULT (getdate()) 
);
go

-- Add data
insert into tempdb.dbo.forms (FormName) values ('Main');
go

-- Show the data
select * from tempdb.dbo.forms;
go


--
-- Sample table 2
--

create table tempdb.dbo.controls
(
ControlId int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
FormID int,
FormControlName varchar(32),
ControlData varchar(32)
);
go

-- Add foreign key 2 forms table
ALTER TABLE tempdb.dbo.controls WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_forms FOREIGN KEY(FormId)
REFERENCES tempdb.dbo.forms (FormID)
go

-- Add data
insert into tempdb.dbo.controls (FormId, FormControlName, ControlData)
values 
(1, 'Drop Down', 'My drop down data'),
(1, 'Text Box', 'My text box');
go

-- Show the data
select * from tempdb.dbo.controls;
go


--
-- Use a join command (1 x N) relationship with where
--

-- Show data from both
select 
    f.FormID,
    f.FormName,
    f.Creator,
    f.CreateDate,
    c.ControlId,
    c.FormControlName,
    c.ControlData 
from 
    tempdb.dbo.forms as f inner join 
    tempdb.dbo.controls as c
on 
    f.FormID = c.FormID 
where 
    f.FormName like '%Main%' and
    c.ControlData like '%box%'
go
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, unfortunately I don't have the access required to modify the database, and because the database is actually part of 3rd party software we are limited to read-only access to it. So unfortunately I don't think your suggestions are of much use to me. Thanks again though.

Comment: Third party databases are not fun.  Good luck!